# Stack Exchange site to ask about making sure a search term is included in the results of a specific search engine

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My original question is as follows:

> When Googling (or whatever search engine) how do I force the search results to include a term (aka all results must have the term)?
>
> I know how to make sure a term is not included (I use the minus sign):
>
> `animals -cats`
>
> the above would search for animals but cannot contain cats. But say I search for 3 things:
>
> `chocolate baseball donkey`
>
> how do I make sure the search result has donkey such that it would be:
>
> `donkey AND (baseball OR chocolate)`

So which Stack Exchange site would this pertain to?

Comment: The correct syntax is usually well explained in the specific search engines help. Did you already consider to read it?

Comment: I doubt it's easy to read and since it's a common problem, let's post an answer somewhere I guess on a stackexchange site

Comment: Well, the opposite of `-`is `+`. Would be natural to try that.

Comment: I would be very surprised if a Stack Exchange site covered a topic this...basic.  It's something that's apparent in the help documents of every search engine in existence, and I would be ***really*** surprised if a Stack Exchange site covered something that's not that tough to negotiate.

Comment: @AlexChannelmeter _"I doubt it's easy to read"_ Why so? Did you even try? It should be written for everyone, even less IT affine people. Also at least google supports an advanced search GUI form to build more complex queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A search engine is kind of a web application, and these kind of questions may be welcomed on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which **behaves like an application**
>
> ...
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But please make sure to search first, in case it has already been asked before: [Google Search: Queries with AND and OR](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115558/136642). It does help if you limit your question to a single search engine; you don't ask a single Stack Overflow question about how to find the length of an array in C#, Java, Python and all other programming languages out there.

Comment: They even have a google-search tag at Web Applications SE.